# Компиляция Python в exe внутри Python кода

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

Есть некий код

```
import PyInstaller.__main__

PyInstaller.__main__.run([
   'some_file.py',
    '--onefile',
])
```

Этот код компилируется через PyInstaller

```
pyinstaller -F code.py
```

Но при запуска `code.py` программа начинает бесконечное повторение компилирования `some_file.py`

Пример

```
154 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.5.1
154 INFO: Python: 3.9.8
505 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
506 INFO: wrote C:\Users\User\Desktop\1123\some_file.spec
509 INFO: UPX is not available.
533 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\folder_with_code', 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\folder_with_code']
```

Можно ли как то это исправить?

Comment: только не написал чего хочешь добиться.

Comment: Я хочу добиться того, что файл `code.exe` мог компилировать `some_file.py` внутри себя

Comment: Ну вот чтобы запустить сам pyinstaller у тебя должен быть установленный питон. Откуда будет код использующий pyinstaller из exe вообще брать необходимые файлы для создания бандла?

Comment: А есть какой-то другой способ выполнить этот алгоритм?

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего это сделать просто дав команду командной строке.
Вот код:

```
from os import system
system('pyinstaller --onefile some_file.py')
```

Разумеется, скрипт с данным кодом должен находиться в одной папке с программой которую требуеться скомпелировать.

Comment: как я понял он хочет получить exe файл, который сможет компилировать в exe файлы python без установки самого питона.